# Pandas: How to combine column int values if different given column is duplicated?

Tags: python, pandas

There are similar questions on Stack Overflow, but none of them have worked for my situation. I've tried working with a combination of `add(...)`, `merge(...)`, `concat(...)`, `drop_duplicates(...)` and more, and I just can't seem to figure it out.

I'm handling data prior to this, and now need to combine the A1, A2, B1, B2, B3, B4, B5, and B6 columns (all type `int`) if ID matches (type `str`). It does not matter what FavoriteFood or Index the new one "inherits".

Given data:

```
Index  FavoriteFood  ID     A1   A2   B1   B2   B3   B4   B5   B6
0      Pizza         0054   0    0    5    5    5    5    5    5
1      Hamburger     0012   0    0    12   12   12   12   12   12
2      Hamburger     0101   70   70   0    0    0    0    0    0
3      Hotdog        0012   21   21   0    0    0    0    0    0
4      Chili         0054   9    9    2    2    2    2    2    2
5      Cookie        2330   0    0    6    6    6    6    6    6
6      Pizza         0020   2    2    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

We have the following matches, based on IDs `0054` and `0012`:

```
Index  FavoriteFood  ID     A1   A2   B1   B2   B3   B4   B5   B6
0      Pizza         0054   0    0    5    5    5    5    5    5
1      Hamburger     0012   0    0    12   12   12   12   12   12
3      Hotdog        0012   21   21   0    0    0    0    0    0
4      Chili         0054   9    9    2    2    2    2    2    2
```

Because `Index`, `FavoriteFood`, and the order of the DataFrame does not matter, the expected DataFrame is:

```
Index  FavoriteFood  ID     A1   A2   B1   B2   B3   B4   B5   B6
0      Pizza         0054   9    9    7    7    7    7    7    7
2      Hamburger     0101   70   70   0    0    0    0    0    0
3      Hotdog        0012   21   21   12   12   12   12   12   12
5      Cookie        2330   0    0    6    6    6    6    6    6  
6      Pizza         0020   2    2    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

How can I combine those columns like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `agg` with a dictionary:

```
agg_dict = {col: 'first' if col in ['FavoriteFood','Index'] else 'sum' 
            for col in df.columns if col!='ID'}
df.groupby('ID', as_index=False, sort=False).agg(agg_dict)
```

Output:

```
     ID  Index FavoriteFood  A1  A2  B1  B2  B3  B4  B5  B6
0  0054      0        Pizza   9   9   7   7   7   7   7   7
1  0012      1    Hamburger  21  21  12  12  12  12  12  12
2  0101      2    Hamburger  70  70   0   0   0   0   0   0
3  2330      5       Cookie   0   0   6   6   6   6   6   6
4  0020      6        Pizza   2   2   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: That solution doesn't give the output posted... I'll read in to the `agg` though thnaks!

Comment: What exactly doesn’t match? You said Index and FavoriteFood are not important right?

Comment: The output DataFrame is the same as the input DataFrame - and yes, Index and FavoriteFood are not important for the combining, but we still need to keep them!

Comment: Are you talking about the different of column orders?

Comment: No, the order doesn’t matter and I’m considering any changes in order - only looking at the output, and I don’t see the effected rows combined

Comment: Are you sure? For example `ID 0012` has `21 21 12 12....` just as in your expected output?

Comment: Maybe I’m messing something up? I’ll check again when I get home! —sorry

Comment: I'm applying your code but the end Data Frame is not being effected, therefore the output is the same as the input... If your's is working from your end I suppose I'm doing something wrong on my mine?

Comment: `df.groupby()` returns a new dataframe. You need to do `df = df.groupby(...)` if you want to change your original dataframe.

Comment: I've been doing `df = df.groupby()`... I just tried your solution on a DataFrame that matched from my question and it worked perfectly. I guess my use-case of it is not good, and somehow not lining up with the question I posted. At least I know it works, so I just need to figure out why it isn't for my use-case. Thanks for answer and further  commenting!

Comment: I'm so dumb I don't want to talk about it. While I was comparing your code to my specific use-case, I noticed a misspelling in variable in the tester class I was using. Here's to 7 days of work! 

Comment: @bananabrann that happens :D